# VB.NET & SQL Server | DataGridView update selected record using DoubleClick event

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, datagridview, sql-server-2012

I have a problem in selecting data in DataGridView using DoubleClick event after I updated one record. I used stored procedure in updating data and sql view to show the other details of selected id (PK).

Below is my code for passing details of the selected id to form application.

```
Private Sub dgvBorrowerMasterlist_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgvBorrowerMasterlist.DoubleClick
  Dim frmEdit As New frmApplication
  Dim dt As New DataTable

  strQuery = "SELECT * FROM VLmsAppMasterlist WHERE BorrowerId ='" & dgvBorrowerMasterlist.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'"
  SelectData(strQuery)

  Try
     da.SelectCommand = cmd
     da.Fill(dt)

     If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim _birthDate As String
        Dim _assessmentTypeId As Char

        txtSearch.Text = String.Empty

        Me.Close()
        CloseAllChild()
        frmEdit.Show()
        frmEdit.EditMode()
        frmEdit.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

        frmEdit.lblBorrowerId2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
        frmEdit.txtLastName.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
        frmEdit.txtFirstName.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
        frmEdit.txtMiddleName.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
        frmEdit.txtNickname.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
        frmEdit.txtAddress.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
        frmEdit.cbOwnership.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item(6)
        frmEdit.txtContactNumber.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(8)
```

And this is my code for updating data using stored procedure.

```
ElseIf btnSubmit.Text = "Save" Then
        cmd = con.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "SpUpdateLoanApplication"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BorrowerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblBorrowerId2.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMiddleName.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nickname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNickname.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OwnershipId", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cbOwnership.SelectedValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtContactNumber.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BirthDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBirthday.Text).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BirthPlace", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBirthPlace.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtAge.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CivilStatusId", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cbCivilStatus.SelectedValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.Image).Value = arrImage
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EntryDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(lblEntryDate2.Text).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss tt")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ModifiedDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = dateFormat
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AutoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Main.lblUserId2.Text.Trim

        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show(Me, "Loan application saved.", "DLIC Lending System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Call LoadMode()
```

I also attached screenshots to show the exact error.

Pic1 shows the masterlist where user can double which record he/she wants to modify.
Pic 2 shows the passed value based on selected PK.
Pic 3 shows the success in modifying selected record.
Pic 4 shows the error after I re-open the masterlist and trying to select another record I want to modify.
Pic 5 is my code for DataGridView doubleclick event.
Pic 6 is the code for updating selected record using SP.

```
[Pic1][1]
[Pic2][2]
[Pic3][3]
[Pic4][4]
[Pic5][5]
[Pic6][6]
```

Comment: 3 things... 1. Always use parameters. 2. Are you sure BorrowerId is a string? 3. Have you considered DataAdapter.Update method?

Comment: BorrowerId is an int. Anyway, this problem was already solved. I declare my cmd as new sqlcommand in SelectData() method. Thanks